# How can I get text value from modal with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-modal, getvalue

I'm fetching the values from my table in ajax.

```
$(data.mesIzinTanimList).each(function (index, element) {

    if (element.izinTanimiVarmi == 'yok')
        tr = "<tr class='bg-warning text-warning-50' row='" + element.userId + "' >";
    else
        tr = "<tr class='bg-light text-white-50 ' row='" + element.userId + "' >";

    tr += "<td>" + element.sicilNo + "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + element.adSoyad + "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + element.bagliOlduguKisi + "</td>";
    tr += "<td>" + element.bagliOlduguKisiSicilNo + "</td>";
    tr += "<td style='display:none'>" + element.bagliOlduguKisiId + "</td>";
    tr += "<td> <button onclick= 'tanimlaBtn(" + element.userId + " , " + element.adiSoyadi + " ," + element.bagliOlduguKisiId + ", " + element.bagliOlduguKisi + ")' type='button' class ='btn btn-info'> Tanımla </button></td>";
    tr += "</tr>";

    $('#IzinTanimListe').append(tr);
});
```

I open a modal with the define Btn onclick feature.

```
function tanimlaBtn(userId, adSoyad, bagliOlduguKisiId, bagliOlduguKisi) {        
    document.getElementById('userId').value = userId;
    document.getElementById('bagliOlduguKisiId').value = bagliOlduguKisiId;
    document.getElementById('bagliOlduguKisi').value = bagliOlduguKisi;
    document.getElementById('adSoyad').value = adSoyad;      
}
```

The `adSoyad` and `bagliOlduguKisi` information appears as undefined. They should be string values.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for the function should be wrapped in doubles quotes and escaped e.g `\"`

Try replacing:

```
<button onclick= 'tanimlaBtn(" + element.userId + " , " + element.adiSoyadi + " ," + element.bagliOlduguKisiId + ", " + element.bagliOlduguKisi + ")'
```

With:

```
<button onclick='tanimlaBtn(" + element.userId + " , " + element.adiSoyadi + " ,\"" + element.bagliOlduguKisiId + "\", \"" + element.bagliOlduguKisi + "\")'
```

Comment: I tried like that but , I take this error; IzinTanimIndex:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input.

  tr += "<td> <button onclick= 'tanimlaBtn('" + element.userId + "' , '" + element.adSoyad + "' ,'" + element.bagliOlduguKisiId + "', '" + element.bagliOlduguKisi + "')' type='button' class ='btn btn-info'> Tanımla </button></td>";